# Does Dir#chdir() change directory virtually?

Tags: ruby

I have the actual directory path : `C:\Documents and Settings\Matt\` Now I here tried the `Dir::chdir()` to see how it works.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Matt>cd..

C:\Documents and Settings>cd..

C:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/"
irb(main):002:0> Dir.chdir('\Documents and Settings')
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Documents and Settings"
```

Now below why got the error,whereas previous `pwd` showing the current directory changed 
as `"C:\Documents and Settings"`?

```
irb(main):004:0> Dir.chdir('\Matt')
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - \Matt
        from (irb):4:in `chdir'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But below it works- Does it mean the chdir did not change the directory to `"C:\Documents and Settings"`? from `C:\` when I used `Dir.chdir('\Documents and Settings')` ?

```
irb(main):005:0> Dir.chdir('\Documents and Settings\Matt')
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Documents and Settings/Matt"
irb(main):007:0>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It changes the working directory of the running program, not virtually. (But not physically in the sense that when you exit, the prompt will show a different directory)

But the backslash at the front refers to the root of the filesystem.

`\Matt`, with a backslash at the beginning, refers to a directory called `Matt` at the *root* of the filesystem, as in `C:\Matt`. That doesn't exist. You want to change the directory relative to `Documents and Settings`, so leave off the backslash.

```
Dir.pwd
=> "C:/"

Dir.chdir('\Documents and Settings')
# Matt is inside Documents and Settings, not at the root \
Dir.chdir('Matt')
# Or use .\ to refer to the current directory
Dir.chdir('.\Matt')
# Even better, use File.join to supply the correct separator, which makes this platform-independent
Dir.chdir(File.join('.','Matt'))
```

If you do this:

```
Dir.chdir('\Matt')
```

... it will attempt to change into the nonexistent `C:\Matt`.

Comment: @DoLoveSky You're welcome. Every answer deserves an explanation, and when you get answers _without_ explanations, I encourage you to pry for them.  An answer with code but no explanation isn't, well, an answer. It's just a solution :) cheers.

Comment: Really helpful you are! If I could get some more like you,I might learn this Lanuguage perfectly at it's core. :)

Comment: This has nothing to with Ruby, this is just how paths in Windows are written.